# SMP disable in Erlang/OTP 20?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

In OTP 20 we can't use `-smp disable` when we start an ERL VM.

So my question is, how can we use another flag to achieve `-smp disable`'s function?

Comment: `erl -smp disable` says `Argument '-smp disable' not supported. Use "+S 1" instead.`. Does `erl +S 1` not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use +S 1 instead of -smp disable

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced "*Argument '-smp disable' not supported. Use "+S 1" instead*" problem when starting RabbitMQ.

Erlang takes `-smp disable` parameter from environment variables with name `ERL_AFLAGS` .Change it's value to `+S 1`